# Join attributes by location fails to join to selected features

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-joins

There's an issue when I perform the "join attributes by location" tool. I have a simple polygon layer representing urban areas. I also have a point layer with human population estimates. My aim is to join the population layer to the urban areas, and have it as a point layer.

Therefore, I've done this:
[image]

This is the polygon layer:

[image]

And this is the point layer:

[image]

Points falling inside the polygons should therefore only be represented. Instead, all the points of my point layer appear in the output, as if nothing happened. I've fixed the geometries of both layers, and I've done this task many times before with no problem. I just don't understand why this is failing to join points only to my polygons.

Comment: @BenW cheers, I've done the "join attributes by location" many times and it worked great. I just don't understand why this is failing to do it correctly now. Could come from one of my layers. Typically, I join points to polygons and it works just fine. I'll give the clip tool a go but I reckon JAL is more suited for my analsis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the points that are not intersecting a polygon to be removed, you would have to check the box `Discard records that could not be joined`